# How to deploy Spark with kubernetes without external spark-submit client

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to dockerize my spark job and deploy it using k8.
Docker documentation provides a way to dockerize spark and we can use that as the base image and update spark with our custom job.

Refer - [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html)

The problem I am facing is deploying this needs a spark-submit client outside the dockerized deployment environment.

[image]

How can I include the spark-submit client in the K8 cluster which can then be deployed using helm and Kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

We can use spark-operator to solve this issue.
Follow the below link and try out a sample example [Spark Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator)

Pre-requisite knowledge of Kubernetes and helm is required.